# How Native app works while there is no wifi connection

Tags: android, ios, performance, reactjs

I would like to know how a native app works while there is no wifi connection. Do I need to do something inside the app's code to save the searched data somewhere inside the app or phone while there is no wifi connection?

I've seen apps that can display the searched data inside the app while wifi is off. How to do works. My data comes from an api and I an going to build an app with REACT JS. Thanks,

Comment: you have to use your own DB for achieve ur goal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chetak Bhimani mention you can use AsyncStorage to cache data. In order to make it easier to manage you can use the REDUX approach, you will still be using the AsyncStorage method but you will not have to manually setItem and getItem.

- https://github.com/reactjs/redux
- https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux
- https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist
- https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

basically this is what I use in my React native applications to manage the state and it work like a charm.

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Ideal configuration to support offline support for webview

webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);//This is must ifincase JS needs to be stored.            webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about webview. You can implement caching and set expiry for cache to never. Then tell the webview to load from cache only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call web-services when internet is available and store data in persistencee storage. if you are creating an app using React-native then you can do like below:

You can use React Native AsyncStorage for storing data to local storage of the device.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
```

Use this to save data

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

AsyncStorage accepts value as only string, so you may need to use **stringify()** before setting the value to AsyncStorage

And to retrieve data use

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('your key');
```